# Does Uranium-235 always split into Krypton and Barium in nuclear fission?

Tags: nuclear-physics

In most nuclear fission examples and exercises, the products of a nuclear fission of Uranium-235 are two light nuclei of Krypton and Barium:

$$\mathrm{ _0^1n + U \longmapsto Kr + Ba + energy }$$

Is there some fission reaction that produces more stable nuclei instead of Krypton and Barium?

Please mention all possible fission equations of Uranium-235.
There's another question, is Uranium-235 the only fissile nucleus?

Comment: In the case of large nuclei things are rarely always the same way. The usual question is *"What is the branching ratio to [some particular state]?"*

Comment: For a detailed description you may read this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission_product) article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't. Here's a [figure from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission_product):

[image: distribution of fission product masses]

Typically there's daughter with mass around 95, a daughter with mass around 140, and two or three extra free neutrons. In discussion of environmental contamination after nuclear accidents, you hear a lot about iodine-133 and strontium-90, because they are relatively long-lived and biologically active. Iodine-133 lives for about a week and accumulates in the thyroid; strontium-90 lives for about 30 years and can replace calcium in bones.

There are several heavy isotopes which can spontaneously fission; the big ones are uranium, plutonium, and californium.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are many nuclei produced by fission.  You should show the mass numbers in any case-you have only specified the division of the protons, not the neutrons.  [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_product) discusses the range of fission products and states that each decay is not predictable, but the probability distribution is measurable.

For the second question, no, $\mathrm U^{235}$ is not the only fissile nucleus.  $\mathrm{Pu}^{239}$ is used in reactors as well.  Many other heavy nuclei will undergo spontaneous fission.