# Why does U-235 split into barium and krypton in nuclear reactors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

For my chemistry project I have found the typical fission reaction which occurs in nuclear power plants is when nuclear fuel rods are bombarded with neutrons, splitting U-235 into isotopes barium and krypton and releasing two more neutrons and massive amounts of heat and energy.

My question is why does bombarding U-235 with neutrons split U-235 into barium and krypton?

Are barium and krypton's nuclei the most stable or does the reaction produce the most energy? My question is what makes the reaction so common in nuclear reactors?

Does the reaction give off the most energy out of all other reactions. Also is the reaction man-made or just a natural nuclear reaction?

Can you also tell me if fuel pellets (U02) are the most efficient type of nuclear fuel or are there more efficient types of nuclear fuel?

Similar question but not same question - [Does Uranium-235 always split into Krypton and Barium in nuclear fission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126285/does-uranium-235-always-split-into-krypton-and-barium-in-nuclear-fission)

Comment: is anybody going to answer?

Comment: Be patient, my friend. Your situation ain’t too bad. Some people here have had their questions unanswered for years.

Comment: okay... But that didn't make me feel any better :(

Comment: It is nonsense, it doesn't decay into these nuclei. Instead of it, there is a very wide nuclei spectrum, with around a hundred different nuclei, barium and krpyton (more precise: one of their isotopes) are only between them, and I am not even sure they had the biggest proportion. You don't get an answer, because soon your question contains a statement, which isn't true.

Comment: And yes, your question is a duplicate, not only similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Uranium-235 always split into Krypton and Barium in nuclear fission?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126285/)

Comment: not a duplicate because I asked questions very different from "Is there some fission reaction that produces more stable nuclei instead of Krypton and Barium?" Look at my questions closely

Comment: There are many isotopic combination among the products of these fissions. Your book has simply picked a common one to use as an example.